# Oracle Database encoding impact on MD5 encryption

Tags: sql, oracle

I am developing an algorithm to detect objects modified by users in a standard database schema. My algorithm is based on MD5 calculation on DDL objects. I am using the DBMS_CRYPTO package.

My question is whether the MD5 hash depends on the  Database original encoding.

Answer (score 2):

The hash md5 or SHA-1 itself don't depend on database encoding because such hashes contain only hex characters. [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/encryption-functions.html)

But before you encode you may need to perform some operations on the data ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm#i1004147))

> The VARCHAR2 datatype is not directly supported by DBMS_CRYPTO. Before you can perform cryptographic operations on data of the type VARCHAR2, you must convert it to the uniform database character set AL32UTF8, and then convert it to the RAW datatype. After performing these conversions, you can then encrypt it with the DBMS_CRYPTO package.